# cannot save images without saveFileDialog visual basic

Tags: vb.net

ive been working on a screenshot program that upload the image automaticly to an FTP server. but i get an error when i try to use:

```
PictureBox1.Image.Save("C:\test.bmp", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp)
```

and i always get the Error:
A generic error occurred in the GDI+
ErrorCode: -2147467259
source- System.Drawing

Full ERROR CODE BELOW (vid = at in english):

```
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException was unhandled
  ErrorCode=-2147467259
  Message="Ett allmänt fel uppstod i GDI+."
  Source="System.Drawing"
  StackTrace:
       vid System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename, ImageCodecInfo encoder, EncoderParameters encoderParams)
       vid mostlyTesting.Form1.Timer1_Tick(Object sender, EventArgs e) i C:\Users\emil\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\mostlyTesting\Form1.vb:rad 22
       vid System.Windows.Forms.Timer.OnTick(EventArgs e)
       vid System.Windows.Forms.Timer.TimerNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       vid System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       vid System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       vid System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(Int32 dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       vid System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       vid System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       vid Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun()
       vid Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.DoApplicationModel()
       vid Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run(String[] commandLine)
       vid mostlyTesting.My.MyApplication.Main(String[] Args) i 17d14f5c-a337-4978-8281-53493378c1071.vb:rad 81
       vid System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
       vid Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       vid System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       vid System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Comment: The picture in the picture box, is it a `Bitmap` already? If so the error is probably because the `Bitmap` is locked and therefore you can't save it... If so, create a new bitmap with the size of the original bitmap, then you have to copy the original bitmap to the new created bitmap. Finally dispose of the original bitmap and then you can save this new `Bitmap` out to file...

Comment: Try saving to a folder like `C:\Temp` - your app may not have access to the root folder of the boot drive

Comment: did not work. stil getting the error.

Comment: @eim64 did you try what I mentioned in my comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is this here

```
Me.PictureBox1.Image.Save(IO.Path.Combine(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop, "TestFile.bmp"))
```

I hope it helps you. Good luck!

Update: 
After I saw Plutonix comment, I tried what he said and It's true, When I try to save the image on C:\ (root folder) It gave me the same error as its giving to you. When I tried with a different path, it worked! The only way is to Run as Administrator and It works for C:\

Comment: After Windows XP, the Root directory is not accessible to regular users, so that would be correct to throw an error -- too bad the error is a vague GDI+ one.